# MS Access Database Confused

Tags: database, ms-access, relationships

I am setting up a database for our hunting club, plus learning access along the way...ouch

I want the database to contain all of the deer observed along with their locations, when the user enters the data it will go as buck/doe/fawn/unknown and they will also enter the location where the deer was observed.  The location could be a stand located at various different places on the property or a stand could be located on a food plot.

Here is where I am confused, I got to this point and really just don't know the best path to follow.  I have followed much of the normalization techniques and set up relationships.  I am working with a form (frmEnterNewStand) to add the stands to the database, what I need is a single combo box with choices that come from two tables (tblProperty Sections for stands not located on food plots) and (tblFoodplots for stands located on food plots). But couldn't figure that one out.  So I attempted to add food plots as another entry but things started getting messy.

Since I am new to this I don't even know the right questions to ask, but I just cannot figure out the best way to organize this to be able to enter data easily then access the data easily.

I know we will want to perform queries to get statistics on, i.e. how many deer were observed blah blah blah, we will also want to query the food plots as well, how many deer were seen on food plot 1 for example, and what time of day.  We will also keep up with other food plot parameters.

I have been taking the Udemy course and have several books, but my mind is blown, any help would be appreciated.

I am going to include an example map of our property, the blue numbers are different sections for the property (tblPropertySections), the yellow S numbers are Stand 1, 2 etc, the orange F numbers are Food Plot 1, 2 etc.

Also included are my current screenshots of what I have so far. I was going to try to post images but I need at least 10 reputation points i guess.

NOt sure what else I need to provide but I will say thank you in advance
tim

thank you
tim

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start simple on this and add complexity as needed.

From my reading of the problem the main outcome is a database that records deer sightings. The easiest possible "database" is just a table that lists the sighting, and associated info.

For example:

```
ID, Date, Time, DeerType, Location, SeenBy, Comments
1, 1/1/2015, 11:45pm, "Doe", "Behind the shed", "Garry Abblet", "After a few beers Garry went for a slash and saw a deer"
```

Start with that and then worry about what needs to be added. I know a single table isn't the most exciting database to learn about, but you should follow a philosophy of the simplest solution usually being the best.

Comment: That is actually how I started with a single table, but then I got to reading about database normalization and relationships and that is when it started getting confusing.  As you mention I may have to go back to square one and add a little at a time.

Comment: I'm still lauging at the comments on yours

Answer (score 0):

Access forms are essentially the visual representation of tables. In fact, if users were just computers you would not need a user interface but can manage processing (edit, add, save, delete) through code. The combo box form control is the tool needed to select corresponding data from other tables, specifically foreign keys.

As you point out, a Stand can either be on a Property Section or Food Plot. So in the tblStands table you can carry two foreign keys: Property Section ID and Food Plot ID.

Then, on their corresponding forms of tblStands the IDs wold be stored/bounded in combo boxes whose RowSources are a queries of the underlying tables:

```
SELECT id, PropertySectionName FROM tblPropertySections

SELECT id, FoodPlotName FROM tblFoodPlots
```

Now, computers would know which ID to pick but not humans who would need names/titles to help identify which item to select. Fortunately, combo boxes come with a special hidden column feature where the IDs can be hidden from view but its related name is presented on the form. However, the ID is stored in table. You set this up with the wizard when you select and position combo boxes.

Manually, or no-wizard approach, you do the following in Property Sheet of selected combo box:

Format tab

```
Column Count: 2 (or any greater than 2 depending on RowSource query)
Column Width: 0"; 1" (or any non-zero that fits into combo box's width)
```

Data tab

```
Control Source: PropertySheetID (or FoodPlotID)
Row Source: (see above queries)
Row Source type: table/query
Bound column: 1
```

Altogether, users will navigate to frmEnterNewStand and choose if the Stand is on Property Section or Food Plot by entering one combo box and not the other (leave label instructions as needed, since users are human).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I need some time to digest this over the next few days and compare this with what I have.

Comment: In doing this I discovered that I have junction tables that may not be needed, the book i'm reading had me set them up, BUT now I read another source that said junction tables are mostly used for many to many relationships, i.e.  a buck could be seen by many hunters and a hunter could see many bucks, so tblBucks and tblHunters would need a junction table, correct.